# How can i prevent duplicate entry in java script while appending data into #div

Tags: javascript, jquery

PFB java script code..

the thing is im getting alert for duplicate entry. how can avoid the repeated data?

```
Var   activityconunt =0;     
  if (activityconunt !== data.iRoundId) {
        alert("duplicate");
        $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" + data.iRoundId + ">" + data.strRoundName + "</option>");             
        }
```

[image: my output] 
my output

Comment: may you create an array with data before to have clean data. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Comment: Very first time its working fine(2nd time only its appending some duplicate data's).

Comment: i tried with breakpoint. the loop is executing more than 9 times instead of 3 times :(

Comment: btw is this a typo `activityconunt` ? shouldnt this be `activitycount` ? and updated my answere with a faster and tested solution. Its way less code the all other solutions. Actually only one line ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution one:**

Take your data and build a clean array before. Using http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

**Solution two:**

Check your existing options for containing values

```
if($("option:contains('" + data.strRoundName + "')").length == 0)
    $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" + data.iRoundId + ">" + data.strRoundName + "</option>");
```

this should do it as well and is a shorter code

also see **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkwth9jf/)**

Comment: hi Dwza its working fine. but im getting one undefined value also in the list :|

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store the data and check the new value with it:

```js
$(function () {
  var items = [];
  var $select = $('select');
  var $input = $('input');
  var $button = $('button');

  // fetch current data
  $select.find('option').each(function () {
    items.push($(this).text());
  });

  $button.on('click', function () {
    var value = $input.val();
    var exists = ($.inArray(value, items) != -1);

    if (! exists) {
      items.push(value);
      $('<option></option').text(value).prependTo($select);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>Add</button>
<br />
<select style="width: 300px;">    
    <option>Hello</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for preventing duplicate values and undefined value in the list

```
  if ($("option:contains('" + data.strRoundName + "')").length == 0 
   && data.strRoundName != null 
   && typeof data.strRoundName != "undefined")
    $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" 
         + data.iRoundId + ">" 
         + data.strRoundName + "</option>");
```