# Append() duplicating list item

Tags: jquery, css

I have read some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095044/how-can-i-prevent-duplicate-entry-in-java-script-while-appending-data-into-div) but it´s not working for me.

I list the data on a listview. When I press the back button on header to repeat the process I want to prevent append() from keeping adding the same list item everytime.

How could I do that? I have used .html() but I am losing css on the second try. I moved **$('#list').append(list_item);** to outside $.each(....) but it didn´t work.

```
$.each(vaga, function(index, item){

  list_item = '<li class="widget uib_w_17" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r" id="listitem"><a href="javascript:ViewItem('+item.ID+');"><span>'+item.CARGO+'</span></a></li>';

});

$('#list').append(list_item);
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media_button_bar/css/media_button_bar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blank App Designer Cordova Web App Project Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
    <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- for your event code, see README and file comments for details -->
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
    <!-- for your init code, see README and file comments for details -->
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
    <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see file for details -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js" data-ver="0"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/ad/jqm_subpage.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/swipe-hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/sidebar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="upage" id="areapage" data-role="page">
        <div class="upage-outer">
            <div data-role="header" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_7" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0" id="header_areas">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"><a class="widget uib_w_25 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" id="opensidebar_btn">Button</a>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_74_57">
                <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_5 row-height-5" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="col uib_col_3 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col left">
                            <p style="font-style: italic; color: #246525;">Select by area</p>
                            <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_7 row-height-7" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="col uib_col_5 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col left">
                            <div class="sbs-container widget uib_w_8 d-margins" data-uib="layout/side_by_side" data-ver="0">
                                <div class="leftContent widget-container">
                                    <a class="uib-graphic-button default-graphic-sizing default-image-sizing hover-graphic-button active-graphic-button default-graphic-button default-graphic-text widget uib_w_10 d-margins media-button-text-bottom" data-uib="media/graphic_button" data-ver="0"
                                    id="admin">
                                        <img src="images/administrativa.png">
                                        <span class="uib-caption">Admin</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>                     

                <!-- LIST PAGE -->

        <div class="upage" id="listpage" data-role="page">
         <div class="upage-outer">
            <div data-role="header" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_15" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0" id="header_listpage">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"><a class="widget uib_w_18 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" id="listpage_back_btn" data-transition="fade">Button</a>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_91_35">
                <div class="widget uib_w_16 ui-content no_wrap outset-margin d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listview" data-ver="0" id="listview">
                    <ul data-role="listview" id="list">

                     <!-- list item appended in js -->
                        <!--<li class="widget uib_w_17" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r" id="listitem"><a href="#"><span>Listitem</span></a>
                        </li>-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: tell me more about 'data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r"' what code or dependency is utlizing these attributes? This is probably where your issue lies.

Comment: @42shadow42 It´s a hybrid app made with intel xdk using jquery framework

Comment: Can you share a snippet of that code that demonstrates how you  are using jquery to hook into those attributes?

Comment: @42shadow42 please take a look at index.html

Comment: I think this is my last question, what file is the first code block in?

Comment: @42shadow42 there is just an index.html and the structure is what I paste above. My js code is inside _index_user_scripts.js_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a framework problem. I changed from jquery to bootstrap and it worked as it should. Empty the list before everything and append it m inside $.each(...)

```
$("#list").empty();

...

$.each(vaga, function(index, item){

  list_item = '<li id="listitem"><a href="javascript:ViewItem('+item.ID+');"><span>'+item.CARGO+'</span></a></li>';

  $('#list').append(list_item);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the list outside of the loop, and append inside like this

```
  $('#list').html('');
  $.each(vaga, function(index, item){
    var list_item = '<li class="widget uib_w_17" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r" id="listitem"><a href="javascript:ViewItem('+item.ID+');"><span>'+item.CARGO+'</span></a></li>';
    $('#list').append(list_item);
  });
```

The styling issues appear to be caused by the inability of your framework to react to dom changes, the first style should be working because it is occurring before the data is processed. You might resolve this by cloning a styled template that existed when the data was processed and adjusting it to fit the data.

Sample coming soon!

Comment: it is losing css on second try even if I use $('#list').append(list_item).trigger('create');

Answer (score 0):

from the post you refer to .. change option to span

```
if($("li.widget span:contains('" + item.CARGO + "')").length == 0){
    // append here
}
```

your code should be something like

```
$.each(vaga, function(index, item){
  if($("li.widget span:contains('" + item.CARGO + "')").length == 0){
    list_item = '<li class="widget uib_w_17" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r" id="listitem"><a href="javascript:ViewItem('+item.ID+');"><span>'+item.CARGO+'</span></a></li>';
    $('#list').append(list_item);
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn´t open on second try

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create all your list elements and then append the result, like this :

```
var list_item = "";

$.each(vaga, function(index, item){
  list_item += '<li class="widget uib_w_17" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r" id="listitem"><a href="javascript:ViewItem('+item.ID+');"><span>'+item.CARGO+'</span></a></li>';
});

$('#list').html(list_item);
```

this way, you modify the DOM only once, better for performance I tink.

Comment: it is losing css on second try